# Moodle - Adding a new Assignment

Tags: php, moodle

I would like to know where does the `INSERT` happen in saving an 'Assignment' in Moodle.

Here's an image.

[image: Adding a new Assignment]

I tweaked the file in  `course/modedit.php` but no changes were made. Maybe it's not placed here or it's located on another folder. Any idea where can I locate it?

Comment: /mod/assign/mod_form.php is where it handles the form, that would be a good place to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addition of modules to courses is controlled by course/modedit.php which handles displaying the module specific creation form (the mod_form.php that Conn references), adding new modules, updateing existing, and probably other stuff as well.

As for where the "actual" inserts happen, there is a call in modedit.php to add_moduleinfo (defined in course/modlib.php), which then calls add_course_module (defined in course/lib.php) that is responsible for inserting into the course_modules table.

Also inside add_moduleinfo is a call to a module defined function, _add_instance (so assign_add_instance in this cause, defined in mod/assign/lib.php), which calls assign::add_instance (defined in mod/assign/locallib.php) which does the actual insertion into the assign table.

---

It looks like you are planning on extending the assign module to add fields to the database. If that's the case, you'll definitely need to alter the add_instance call, as well as the update_instance call.

You'll also have to edit assign/mod_form.php to include your form element (modedit.php isn't the right place to do that since it would apply to all module forms unless you put a check for an assign module, but that's kinda kludgey).

You will also have to alter the table itself to add the new column, ideally editing both the mod/assign/db/install.xml and mod/assign/db/upgrade.php so new installs and upgrades work the same.

And whenever you make schema changes, you need to increment the version in mod/assign/version.php.

If you want your new setting to be kept when your assignments are backed up and restored, you'll also have to edit the mod/assign/backup/moodle2/backup_assign_stepslib.php and possibly mod/assign/backup/moodle2/restore_assign_stepslib.php as well.

And then of course you'll want to USE this new field, but I'll leave that up to you.

Hopefully this has helped.